# A curve intersected by a straight line having constant harmonic mean segments

Tags: geometry, locus

[image]

It is known that the if the product of two line segments OA,OB drawn from any point O to a curve is a constant, then the curve  is a circle (black). The product is the square of the geometric mean.

However what is another curve (green) if harmonic mean of OA,OB  is a constant?

Thanks for all suggested insights or the curve itself if already known.

Answer (score 1):

I have understood that you would like to find a type of curve such that, **whatever the pole $O$** we have, for any secant line issued from $O$ :

$$\text{HarmMean(OA,OB)=constant}$$

What I am giving below is a solution restricted to the case of a fixed pole (taken as the origin) ; nevertheless, it is a "piece of the puzzle" helping in the direction of finding either a general solution... or a proof that such a general type of curve doesn't exist.

The particular solution  I propose (a self-invariant curve with respect to its center)is in fact the **union of two curves** with resp. polar equations :

$$\begin{cases}r_1(t)&=&\frac{\tan(t)}{1+\tan(t)}&&& (0 \le t \le 3 \pi/4 \ \ \text{blue curve})\\
r_2(t)&=& \frac{\tan(t)}{\tan(t)-1}&=&-\frac{r_1(t)}{2r_1(t)-1} &(\pi/4 \le t \le \pi\ \ \text{red curve})\end{cases}$$

(the two line asymptotes are not part of the curve).

[image]

Comment: Cubic curves have special properties regarding harmonic mean ; for example, see this [old book](https://ia600204.us.archive.org/20/items/lecturesontheory00gangrich/lecturesontheory00gangrich.pdf) (author : S. Gangrich) and ask, using "Ctrl S", with keywords "harmonic mean"

Comment: Whereas the curve I propose is a quartic (it can be given under the form $(x^2+y^2)(x+y)^2-y^2=0$).

Comment: I thought again to your problem : as you assume *implicitely* that a secant intersects the curve in (at most) 2 points, it means that you are looking for a convex curve (the curve of my answer isn't...). It is to be mentionned that possible generalizations of the concept of "power of a point with respect to a curve" have been explored like in this interesting article:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261777175_The_power_of_a_point_for_some_real_algebraic_curves/link/5a1b20430f7e9be37f9be916/download?_tp=eyJjb250ZXh0Ijp7ImZpcnN0UGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIiwicGFnZSI6InB1YmxpY2F0aW9uIn19

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question was for the *same* curve with one  equation ( with line through origin making two intersections on the same curve) , the ODEs of the curves are different, union has third order discontinuity.

Comment: Just saw your previous connected [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4503810/305862)

Comment: Yes, there we had a circle and straight line (different curves) and a line through a fixed point cutting out two segments that  make for a  constant harmonic mean.

Comment: Meanwhile I am looking at at an ( extended ) epicycloid like spiral solution I obtained, for its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

A solution obtained  when O,A,B are not always collinear, even if derived on that basis. Could be due to some inherent precession? in the spiral.

A circle radius $a$ is drawn through A,B, centred on their perpendicular bisector. Let

$$OB=r, OA= r- 2 a \sin \psi, \psi= \psi(s), r'(s)= \cos \psi $$

Constant  Harmonic mean
$$H=\frac{r  (r- 2 a \sin \psi)}{(r-  a \sin \psi)} \tag1$$
Differentiate wrt arc $s$ using Chain Rule, cancelling $\cos \psi$ at RHS
$$ H= \frac{2 r ~- 2 a \sin \psi  - 2 a r \sin \psi }{1- a \psi'(s)}$$
Cross multiply, simplify to get ode of desired curve
$$ a \psi ' =1 +\frac{2 a \sin \psi}{r}  \left(\frac{ a \sin \psi}{r} -1\right)  \tag 2$$
From (1)
At tangent point $$ \psi=0, ~ H=r= r_{tangent}$$
At $$~ \psi = \pi/2, ~r_{max}= a+ H/2 + \sqrt{a^{2}+H^{2}} \tag 3$$
At $ \psi =3 \pi/2$
$$\psi =3 \pi/2,~~r_{min}=- a+ H/2 - \sqrt{a^{2}+H^{2}},~r_{max}- r_{min}= 2a\tag 4$$

Also from (1)
$$  H= \frac{ r_{max}.(r_{max}-2 a)}{r_{max}-a} = \frac{ r_{min}.(r_{min}+2 a)}{r_{min}+a} ;  \tag5 $$

The spiral drawn to input $ a=1, H=1$ results in extreme radii (1,3) calculated by above relations in the advancing spiral:

[image]